# How to set a javascript function to an element with no postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I created an `input type=file` and I need to connect it to my Javascript function, the problem is that I get postback (I don't need server-side), I tried different ways (code below).. maybe I set the function wrong... Help please
++ createMyButton is fired from another function and works fine.

```
//JAVASCRIPT
function createMyButton(){
 var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
        deleteBtn.type = "button";        
        deleteBtn.title = "Delete"; 
     //1 try
        deleteBtn.onclick = 'deleteItem()'; 
     //2 try
          deleteBtn.onclick = 'deleteItem();return false'; 

}
//FUNCTION 
 function deleteItem() {

        alert("delete");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you create a jsFiddle to illustrate the issue?
Firstly, your JS appears to be malformed. Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: One issue I see is that `deleteBtn.onclick = 'deleteItem();return false';` will not work. could be `deleteBtn.onclick = function() { deleteItem(); return false; };` I don't really know that that would help you though.

Answer (score 0):

These are the issue I seen

1.`deleteBtn.onclick = 'deleteItem();'`  are you missing quote `"''`here ?

2
. If u want to bind event to element use `addEventListener` to for 
  E.g

```
        var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
        deleteBtn.type = "button";        
        deleteBtn.title = "Delete"; 
        // you missed button value here 
        deleteBtn.value = "Delete"; 
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);


        //FUNCTION 
       function deleteItem() {
        var btn = this; // you can use button here 

        alert("delete");
       }
```

[JSBIN EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/riqopacarahi/1/)

Comment: looks nice but is there an option to pass data to my function using addEventListener